# Gradle Dependencies Download Jars

Tags: android, docker, gradle

I'm trying to find a gradle task that will ensure that all of the dependency artifacts are downloaded into the gradle cache. If I run `./gradlew :project:dependencies`, I can look at `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches`, and I can see a lot of `com.x.package/artifact/version/hash/` directories, but they mostly (only?) contain `.pom` files. How do I ensure that `.jar` files are also downloaded?

For context, I'm attempting to build a docker image that has the gradle cache pre-built to avoid downloading artifacts every time.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
   task showMeCache << {
    configurations.compile.each { println it }
   }
```

If you run it , it should download dependencies and print the location of the cached dependencies.

It may depend on your platform but the artifacts should be stored here:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

Comment: I get a syntax error with that code. If I modify it to `tasks.register("showMeCache") { doLast { etc } }`, it doesn't print anything at all.

I did find directories for all my artifacts in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`, but most of them only contain a `.pom` file, not the `.jar`

Comment: That should indeed be the location of jars, per gradle docs. Try deleting the dirs under the caches folder and rebuilding like this :  ./gradlew --build-cache clean assemble

Comment: I tried using `--build-cache`, but some artifact directories still only have `.pom` files. Doing a full assemble unfortunately won't help, because I'm trying to do this with just the gradle files. In order to assemble, I'd have to add the entire codebase to Docker, which would defeat the purpose of trying to cache just the dependencies

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using? I see a similar complaint in gradle forums for versions older than 3.5.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 5.2

Comment: I'm using the Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1 - is that the one you meant?